# update column value in laravel 5.4

Tags: database, laravel, phpmyadmin, postman, database-migration

> i want to update privacy of a post
>
> my controller

```
   public function changePostsPrivacy(Request $request){
            $userId = $request->user()->id;
            $postid = $request->get('id');
            //dd($postid);
            $privacy = $request->get('privacy');//dd($privacy);
            $user = User::where(['id' => $userId, 'hide' => 0])->first();
            if($user && $postid && in_array($privacy, [1,0])){
                DB::table('posts')->update(['creator_id' => $userId, 'id' => $postid],[
                    'privacy' => $privacy,
                ]);
            }
        }
```

> Route :

```
 Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth:api', \App\Http\Middleware\OnlyRegisteredUsers::class]], function(){
        /**
         * Group for registered users only APIs
         */
        Route::post('changePostsPrivacy','UserController@changePostsPrivacy');
    });
```

> Migration

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('content');
            $table->string('short_description');
            $table->unsignedInteger('media_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('media_id')->references('id')->on('medias');
            $table->unsignedInteger('creator_id');
            $table->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->boolean('hide')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

> new column added in this this migration

```
 public function up()
        {
            Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('privacy')->after('creator_id');
            });
        }
```

> when i want to add privacy to any post it gives me an error
>
> "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`webdb`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_post_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`)) (SQL: update `posts` set
>   `creator_id` = 17, `id` = 48)",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u must use where condition in update privacy post

```
DB::table('posts')->where(['creator_id' => $userId, 'id' => $postid])->update(['privacy' => $privacy])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this.

```
$post = Post::where(['creator_id' => $userId, 'id' => $postid])->first();
$post->privacy = $privacy;
$post->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Post model you can do :

```
Post::where(['creator_id' => $userId, 'id' => $postid])->update(['privacy' => $privacy]);
```

To prevent any foreign key error, you should use a [validation request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation) to check whether that the provided `user_id` and `post_id` [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-exists).

Comment: yes , i have tried that,i sending data from postman ,when i send 1, 0 or empty field it works but when i pass any other data it gives me an error

Comment: Sending data from POSTMAN usually fail as your route must be protected with the CSRF token middleware. So you need a valid token to POST with your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function changePostsPrivacy(Request $request){
            $userId = $request->user()->id;
            $postid = $request->get('id');
            $privacy = $request->get('privacy');
            $user = User::where(['id' => $userId, 'hide' => 0])->first();
            if($user && $postid && in_array($privacy, [1,0])){
                DB::table('posts')->update([
                    'privacy' => $privacy,
                ]);
            }
```

creator id and id is not required to update.